# Different Navigation Bars and Footer on another page Angular

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, angular-components

Angular CLI: 9.1.7

I am fairly new to Angular and would like some assistance with displaying an entirely different top navigation bar, sidebar and footer when the user navigates to other components outside of home, login, sign up and forgot password.

On the dashboard, the new top navigation bar and side bar are displayed but the old navigation bar `<app-header></app-header>` and footer `<app-footer></app-footer>` is still being displayed.

How do I get  `<app-header></app-header>`  and  `<app-footer></app-footer>` to not be displayed when the user is not on the home, login, sign up and forgot password pages?

*app.component.html*

```
 <!-- header -->
<app-header></app-header>
    
<!-- routes will be rendered here -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- footer -->
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'apptitle';
}
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  component: HomeComponent
},
{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
},
{
  path: 'signup',
  component: SignupComponent
},
{
  path: 'forgot-password',
  component: ForgotPasswordComponent
},
{
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent
},
if the user tries to navigate to a page that is not there
  { path: '**',
  component:  HomeComponent}
];
```

*dashboard.component.html*

```
<app-top-menu-bar></app-top-menu-bar>
<app-side-menu-bar></app-side-menu-bar>
<app-small-footer></app-small-footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put activate to router-outlet in app.component.ts

```
<router-outlet (activate)="showHide($event)"></router-outlet>
```

in app.component.ts

```
isShow=true;
showHide(event){
    if(event instanceof YourComponent) {this.isShow=false}else{ this.isShow=true};
 }
```

in html use with ngIf

```
<app-header *ngIf="isShow"></app-header>
    
<!-- routes will be rendered here -->

<app-footer *ngIf="isShow"></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally add a new route for example newCompWithDifferentHeaderAndFooter, this would contain the different header and footer, I would do this if want the user to see the difference a different url. But if the url must remain intact I would just swap the head and footer for the correct ones.

Remember if you go with the new route approach you will have to add a new route, and if you want to be extra organized put the current header and footer inside a folder with Footer or Header name and put specific name to each header and footer for easier way to find them.